# Auto start xampp in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lamp, xampp

Every time I start or restart my Ubuntu 16, Xampp doesn't start I have start manually by `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`. Making script like `sudo nano /etc/init.d/lampp` doesn't work command `update-rc.d lampp defaults` gives me error:

```
insserv: warning: script 'K01lampp' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'lampp' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: fopen(.depend.stop): Permission denied
```

The script File contains the below lines:

```
[#!/bin/bash

/opt/lampp/lampp start]
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. - First move that particular script to /etc/init.d/  Directory

for example

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/lampp
#

# Some things that run always
touch /var/lock/lampp

# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting script lampp "
    echo "Could do more here"
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping script lampp"
    echo "Could do more here"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/lampp {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Once you've saved your file into the correct location make sure that it's executable by running "chmod 755 /etc/init.d/lampp".

Then you need to add the appropriate symbolic links to cause the script to be executed when the system goes down, or comes up.

*it's this way

```
root@root:~# update-rc.d lampp defaults
```

2.Do it using GUI

- **STARTUP APPLICATION**[image]

Comment: I tried making a symbolic link but gives me error:

`ln: failed to create symbolic link '/opt/lampp/lampp': File exists`

Comment: The file which i have made is in `/etc/init.d/lampp`  and the original file is in `/opt/lampp/lampp` .

Comment: /opt/lampp/lampp this the main file which i use to start xampp `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

Comment: Try my answer below. That should be much more easy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer which has helped me, Akhil Varma.
I have expanded your script a bit more to fully support the `service` command fully. Please refer to my answer below for my sharing. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is rather simple.

Simply open terminal and write

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

And then add these 2 lines just before the last line

```
cd /opt/lampp/
sudo ./lampp start
```

And that's it. Simply save and restart the computer. Please note that these lines should be above the last line that says `exit 0`

I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answer which has helped me, Akhil Varma.

Based on the earlier from Akhil Varma, I would like to share a modified version for /etc/init.d/lampp to support `service` or `systemctl` command fully. Please make sure the command used and file created is done in root.

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/lampp
#

# Some things that run always touch /var/lock/lampp

# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system case "$1" in   start)
    echo "Starting script lampp "
    /opt/lampp/lampp start
    /opt/lampp/lampp startftp
    ;;   status)
    echo "Status of script lampp"
    /opt/lampp/lampp status
    if test -f /opt/lampp/logs/httpd.pid 
    then
      exit 0
    else
      exit 3
    fi
    ;;   stop)
    echo "Stopping script lampp"
    /opt/lampp/lampp stop
    ;;   *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/lampp {start|stop|status}"
    exit 1
    ;; esac

exit 0
```

This is assuming the installation directory for LAMPP/XAMPP is at `/opt/lampp`. Change accordingly if your LAMPP/XAMPP installation directory is different.

Make sure the `/etc/init.d/lampp` is executable by:

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/lampp
```

To enable auto-start for LAMPP/XAMPP service:

```
update-rc.d lampp defaults
```

You can now use the following `service` command as follows, and it will report correctly:

```
service lampp status
service --status-all
```

or

```
systemctl status lampp
```

To start/stop the lampp manually:

```
service lampp start
service lampp stop
```

or

```
systemctl start lampp
systemctl stop lampp
```

Hope it helps.